# add rows in pyspark dataframe and adjust the column sequence accordingly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We have a dataframe like  below say DF1

| col_name | col_seq | Hash_enc_ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 0 |
| first_name | 2 | 1 |
| last_name | 3 | 1 |
| full_name | 4 | 1 |
| XYZ | 5 | 0 |
| sal | 6 | 1 |
| AAA | 7 | 0 |

Now I want to add 2 rows for one row where hash_inc_ind =1 and adjust the col seq accordingly so that the output would be like

DF1:

| col_name | col_seq | Hash_enc_ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 0 |
| first_name_h | 2 | 1 |
| first_name_e | 3 | 1 |
| last_name_h | 4 | 1 |
| last_name_e | 5 | 1 |
| full_name_h | 6 | 1 |
| full_name_e | 7 | 1 |
| XYZ | 8 | 0 |
| sal_h | 9 | 1 |
| sal_e | 10 | 1 |
| AAA | 11 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You can explode an array constructed using when:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'col_name', 
    F.expr("explode(transform(case when Hash_enc_ind = 1 then array('_h', '_e') else array('') end, x -> col_name || x))")
)

df2.show()
+------------+-------+------------+
|    col_name|col_seq|Hash_enc_ind|
+------------+-------+------------+
|         abc|      1|           0|
|first_name_h|      2|           1|
|first_name_e|      2|           1|
| last_name_h|      3|           1|
| last_name_e|      3|           1|
| full_name_h|      4|           1|
| full_name_e|      4|           1|
|         XYZ|      5|           0|
|       sal_h|      6|           1|
|       sal_e|      6|           1|
|         AAA|      7|           0|
+------------+-------+------------+
```